# Salesforce Not loading D3 V3 Script

Tags: d3.js, static, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I uploaded my d3 version 3 javascript file in a static resource in Salesforce. But when I am trying to load the script in my javascript facing resource not found issue.

I am able to load D3 V4 javascript file. But when I am trying to load D3 V3 file facing the following error. I have the requirement to load d3 v3 script only

[image]

Javascript code to load d3 v3 script is below

[image: Load D3 V3 code]

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found

What happens if you try to click the link in the line with error. It should take you to page where you can see JavaScript code. If it fails on such click - it'll also fail when requested from script.

Post more code, what's in "D3" variable. I suspect your zip file uploaded as static resource doesn't have just 3 files free-floating. They probably got zipped with the folder in which you had them so now either you repackage it or you build your path like `D3 + '/somefolder/d3.v3.min.js'`. Or maybe there's a typo in the filename.

Either way - click the link in the URL and keep experimenting in address bar until you manage to see the file, then adjust your code (or zip). Is it only the JS file that fails or CSS too?

Comment: I was able to load d3 v4 script. Zip file has one d3 v4, d3v3 and one css files. Not able to do with d3 v3